# kernel panic on iMac late 2013

Tags: usb, ssd, crash, kernel-panic

I have a problema with my imac, i keep getting a random kernel panic and rebbot, any solution?

i think is important to say that i got osx installed on an external SSD connected trhough a usb 3 case, few times a day i got these reboots followed by kernel panic errors logs. (also got connected an external monitor through thunderbolt-hdmi adapter)

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xffffff7f8a771a8d): watchdog timeout: no checkins from watchdogd in 94 seconds (267 total checkins since monitoring last enabled)
Backtrace (CPU 1), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff810bf2bc40 : 0xffffff800971c63d 
0xffffff810bf2bc90 : 0xffffff8009856b25 
0xffffff810bf2bcd0 : 0xffffff80098486ae 
0xffffff810bf2bd20 : 0xffffff80096c2a40 
0xffffff810bf2bd40 : 0xffffff800971bd07 
0xffffff810bf2be40 : 0xffffff800971c0f7 
0xffffff810bf2be90 : 0xffffff8009ec0ba8 
0xffffff810bf2bf00 : 0xffffff7f8a771a8d 
0xffffff810bf2bf10 : 0xffffff7f8a77147b 
0xffffff810bf2bf50 : 0xffffff7f8a786d9c 
0xffffff810bf2bfa0 : 0xffffff80096c213e 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.driver.watchdog(1.0)[6269905F-7EFE-30D3-AB0F-68AF13BC33E7]@0xffffff7f8a770000->0xffffff7f8a778fff
         com.apple.driver.AppleSMC(3.1.9)[4E9DE5FB-961B-3743-AF54-D82B679F540C]@0xffffff7f8a779000->0xffffff7f8a797fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[94739858-1444-3051-9353-F838BE561495]@0xffffff7f8a767000
            dependency: com.apple.driver.watchdog(1)[6269905F-7EFE-30D3-AB0F-68AF13BC33E7]@0xffffff7f8a770000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[EBF1EE2C-3FBC-3BB4-BB9A-D1F120364896]@0xffffff7f8a131000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: kernel_task

Mac OS version:
19H1217

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.6.0: Thu May  6 00:48:39 PDT 2021; root:xnu-6153.141.33~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 0B6CD26B-B526-3646-9B69-02D22BBE9C52
Kernel slide:     0x0000000009400000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8009600000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009500000
System model name: iMac14,1 (Mac-031B6874CF7F642A)
System shutdown begun: NO
Panic diags file available: NO (0xe00002bc)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 27723810478629
last loaded kext at 17151155751: >!A!BHIDKeyboard   209 (addr 0xffffff7f8cacc000, size 16384)
last unloaded kext at 27640316274126: >!A!ILpssGspi 3.0.60 (addr 0xffffff7f8c88c000, size 45056)
loaded kexts:
@fileutil   20.036.15
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>AGPM   111.4.4
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>!AMikeyHIDDriver   131
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
>!AHDA  283.15
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 5.2.7
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   5.2.7
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.6f8
>pmtelemetry    1
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!A!IHD5000Graphics 14.0.7
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.4
>!A!IFramebufferAzul    14.0.7
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AMikeyDriver  283.15
>eficheck   1
>!AMCCSControl  1.14
>!ASMCLMU   212
>!ALPC  3.1
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AVirtIO   1.0
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.100.5
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.141.2
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>AirPort.BrcmNIC    1400.1.1
>!ASDXC 1.7.7
|!ABCM5701Ethernet  10.3.5
>!AAHCIPort 341.140.1
>!ARTC  2.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!AHPET 1.8
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>!A!BHIDKeyboard    209
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.6f8
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
@kext.triggers  1.0
>DspFuncLib 283.15
@kext.OSvKernDSPLib 529
>!AGraphicsControl  5.2.7
|IOAVB!F    850.1
@!AGPUWrangler  5.2.7
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.3
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    5.2.7
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.7.4
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
|IONDRVSupport  576.1
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
|IOGraphics!F   576.1
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    840.3
|Broadcom!BHost!CUSBTransport   7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CUSBTransport 7.0.6f8
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.6f8
|IO!B!F 7.0.6f8
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.6f8
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!UAudio    323.4
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IOSurface  269.11
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.6
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.4
|IOAHCIBlock!S  316.100.5
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.6
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.6.1
|IO80211!F  1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
|IOAHCI!F   290.0.1
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>DiskImages 493.0.0
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!ASSE  1.0
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.120.1
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.120.3
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.140.1
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.120.3
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|IOReport!F 47
|IOTimeSync!F   840.3
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.Libm   1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
```

Comment: It is not clear what you’re asking.  You have entered this info in a field that is designed for questions.

Comment: yeah, i edited to be more clear, thank you.

Comment: Did your internal iMac drive fail? Is that why you are booting macOS off an external USB3 SSD?

Comment: No, the internal drive is OK and I use it as storage drive, I added the external one for performance reason